# Jquery tabs UI issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

Jquery Tabs issue:

Hi am facing issue with Jquery tabs UI.

.vbhtml :

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tabs').tabs();
    });
</script>

 <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
 </div>
```

in my _Layout.vbhtml :

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Getting this error:

```
0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tabs'
```

Tried doing many things and couldn't find any solution. Might be missing a basic thing but not able to figure out the issue.
Any help will be lot helpful for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the order to:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is working. Am new to jquery and need some information. can you tell me briefly, what are the necessary needed files we need to include in visual studio in order to work with Jquery ? both the script and css files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @Robert Rozas' solution should work. The jQuery plugin should be used first before loading jQuery UI plugin which is dependent on jQuery plugin.